# How to hide my page for other browsers except for chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, show-hide

How can i hide my webpage for other browsers and make it viewable for Chrome only?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
<p> Hide me on all browsers except for Chrome! <p>
</div>
```

I want the content class to be viewable for Chrome only and not for other browsers like Firefox and Safari

Comment: There are some libraries available on the internet which do some browser detect stuff. However, it can be tricked by modifying the user agent. See https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var chrome   = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1;
var explorer = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1;
var firefox  = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1;
var safari   = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;

if(!chrome) {
   // Hide stuff
}
```

Not 100% reliable (like most solutions), but simple and worked for what I needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isChromium = window.chrome,
    winNav = window.navigator,
    vendorName = winNav.vendor,
    isOpera = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("OPR") > -1,
    isIEedge = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1,
    isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");

if (isIOSChrome) {
//    is Google Chrome on IOS
} else if (
  isChromium !== null &&
  typeof isChromium !== "undefined" &&
  vendorName === "Google Inc." &&
  isOpera === false &&
  isIEedge === false
) {
document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
    $("body *:not(.info)").hide();

} else { 
document.getElementById("content").style.display = "none";
}
```

This is the code that worked for me